# Bash, interactive script that switch between options with a keypress combination?

Tags: bash

E.g., I wish to have a shell script that, with a key combination (for example CTRL S, or maybe with a signal) allow me to switch between 2 or more options in runtime, like:

- print the number of process on system every 5 seconds
- CTRL S
- print the current time
- CTRL S
- again print the number of process on system every 5 seconds
- CTRL S
- print the current time

etc...

I use this construct, maybe someone could suggest another, more elegant, form:

```
while true; do
    echo a
    read -t5 -n1
done
while true; do
    echo b
    read -t5 -n1
done
source ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Do you actually have a mechanism to do one of these two things in place already and just need to know how to toggle between them based on a signal or keypress, or are you *also* asking someone to tell you how to set up a periodic update (to the prompt or whatnot)? Note that a good SO question is narrowly scoped -- asking how to trap a signal and toggle a variable is a better question than including the *things you want to do based on that variable's value* in-scope. Which is to say, a larger number of narrow questions is better than a small number of broad ones...

Comment: ...in part because the narrow questions are likely to have already been asked and answered, so when you break your question down into slices, you can only ask about the specific aspects that nobody has already tried to do (and gotten assistance/instruction on already in our knowledge base) in the past.

Comment: [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)? [tmux](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1)? Run two terminals on a terminal multiplexer, one with `while sleep 5; do ps aux | wc -l; done` the second with `while sleep 1; do date; done` and you can switch between them using (CTRL+B)+0 or (CTRL+B)+1 in tmux?

Comment: No, i just need to know how to toggle between 2 or more commands (like a wheel, so that scripts not exit on last command but restart from first command), not that specifics commands in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't do *quite* what you're asking for: it spits out the number of processes every 5 seconds, and responds at any time to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to emit the current time.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
puts "hit ctrl+T for the current time"
spawn -noecho sh -c {while :; do ps a | wc -l; sleep 5; done}
interact \024 {puts [timestamp -format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"]}
```

I chose Ctrl+T to avoid clashing with Ctrl+S that pauses the terminal.

---

A command switcher that responds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

```
#!/bin/bash

trap switch_command INT

switch_command() { 
    (( idx = (idx + 1) % ${#commands[@]} ))
    echo "switch to: ${commands[idx]}"
}

commands=(count_procs show_time)
idx=0

count_procs() { ps a | wc -l; }
show_time() { date; }

echo "Ctrl+C to switch commands"
echo "'kill $$' to stop"
while :; do
    "${commands[idx]}"
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: thanks glenn, but it's not what i've asked:
i use that 2 commands just for example.
I need a way to switch between 2 commands in a script with a key combination

Comment: I solved with a switcher that responds to Ctrl-C, but mystery about the behavior of `trap command SIGQUIT` remains

Comment: Well, there are some signal that cannot be trapped, and apparently there are some signals that cannot be *completely* trapped.

Comment: @glennjackman Nice script. Any chance you can explain how it works. I need a wallpaper switcher and this looks like it's ideal, but I don't know how it works, or how I would get it into `.bashrc` the way it's formatted. How does the `switch_command()` function get called? It's not obvious to me. I'm trying to set up a script to toggle between any of 4 specific wallpapers on a key combination.