# Best way to switch between top and tail -f

Tags: bash, multitasking

I need to monitor both CPU usage and a specific log file and switch between them regularly.

Is there a better way than Ctrl+C, up-arrow, up-arrow, Enter? (And optionally also re-configuring top each time to sort by mem)

Ideally, with just one key stroke.

I know I can workaround with two terminal windows and Alt-Tab, but I have to also do a lot of other work and having to juggle that extra window is inconvenient.

Comment: Why don't you just set two terminal windows side by side to be able to see both at once?)

Comment: Or use a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is by using infinite while loop.

**Code:**

```
while : ;do top -n 5 -o %MEM; timeout 5 tail -f /path/to/your_log.log; done
```

**Explanation:**

`top -n 5` - Allows you to specify after how many refreshes (Default refresh time is 3 seconds.) should top command quit. (The top command will exit after 5 refreshes in this example)
`top -o %MEM` - To sort by memory usage.
`timeout 5` - timeout exits command after given interval. (5 seconds in this example).

You can change the time interval of `top` and `timeout` as per your requirement.

To break out of the loop you can use `Ctrl+C`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, but not exactly what I'm looking for (automatic switch by timeout vs. user pressing key)

Comment: Ah, got it now. Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745220/bash-interactive-script-that-switch-between-options-with-a-keypress-combination) might help then.

Comment: For me in `bash`, the loop continues even after pressing `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @user14967413 In that case the maybe first command must be running when you pressed `Ctrl+C`. Did you try pressing `Ctrl+C` twice ?

Comment: @mrrobot.viewsource No matter how many times i press `Ctrl+C`, the loop still continues. I run the loop directly from the command line. When I run it from separate script executed via `bash` it behaves the same. When I execute it with `.`, `Ctrl+C` sudenly works.

Comment: ok. Seems to be working fine for me. I am on CentOS 7.9